# How should I display the content of the database in CActiveForm?

Tags: yii

Now I am building the view of a website and I use the widget CActiveForm as the view. However, I need to display some of the contents of the database, for example, the result of a SQL query. Then what should I do to accomplish the goal? Thank you!

Some of my code is provided below:

```
<div class="form">
<?php

$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
));

?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row radiobuttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList(
            $Paper,
            'Q1No',
            array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B','C'=>'C','D'=>'D'),
            array('template'=>'<span class="radio">{input}{label}</span>','separator'=>'')); 
        ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

This is my code. And I need to add some contents of the database in the form. The content is listed below:

```
    public function actionTaketest()
    {
        // Get the ID of the test paper from the URL ---ztm
        if(isset($_GET['paperid']))
        {
            $paperid=(int)$_GET['paperid'];
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase';
            $username = 'root';
            $password = '000000';

            $connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);

            // establish connection. You may try...catch possible exceptions
            $connection->active=true;

            $rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('*')
                ->from('Paper, Question') array(':PaperNo'=>$paperid))
                ->queryAll();

            $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
                'id'=>'PaperNo',
            ));


            $connection->active=false; // close connection


            $model=new LoginForm;
            $this->render('form',array('model'=>$model, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));

        }
        else
        {
            // Deny illegal access to the page ---ztm
            throw new CHttpException(404,'invalid request');
        }
    }
```

This code are in the controller.

Comment: CActiveForm is a widget for html forms. Why do you want to use it for view? Your question isn't clear, please provide some code snippet.

Comment: In login.php, which is automatically generated, the widget is used for view and this is why I want to use it in the view. I write a php file as below:  I am terribly sorry that I faild to paste the code here right now. I will go to see the help first before I provide the code.

Comment: what content from the database do you want to show? and how is it related to the data collected in the form? your question is still unclear

Comment: Thanks bool.dev, I succeeded in pasting the code in this way. But I failed to make the code clear enough when I was trying to remove the bugs in the code. So I just paste the automatically generated code that is used for login here. Is it enough? Or should I try to paste my own source code here? If it is necessary, I will go to make some modifications to the code so that it will be understandable.

Comment: just paste your code, let's see how it is..i have posted another comment, can you reply to that also "what content from the database do you want to show? and how is it related to the data collected in the form?"

Comment: Well, and so I should paste the contens of the controller?

Comment: yes if you think it can help in understanding

Comment: so your main doubt is how to display the data in the `$dataProvider`? or how to put data into the `$dataProvider`?

Comment: Sorry for not expressing my problem clearly. I am wondering how should I display the data in $dataProvider in the CActiveForm.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too messy, and looks invalid in some places. First of all you don't need to create CDbConnection in controller, you can specify credentials in config. To read data from database you can use [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record):

```
$paper = Paper::model()->findByAttributes(array('PaperNo' => $paperid));
```

And then in your html:

```
echo CHtml::activeRadioButtonList(
        $paper,
        'Q1No',
        array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B','C'=>'C','D'=>'D'),
        array('template'=>'<span class="radio">{input}{label}</span>','separator'=>'')
);
```

I hope it helps a little bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I will try to use ActiveRecord to see whether it works. Sorry for not making the code understandable. Just as I said, when I was trying to fix the code, I make some modifications to the code, but I have not finish debugging and maybe there are some mistakes in the program.

Comment: But I still do not know what should I do if I am to display the things out?

Comment: What do you mean "to display the things out". If you need to print some column of model, simply `echo $paper->PaperNo` or `echo $paper->Q1No`.

Comment: I forget to use it. Well, I will have a try. Thank you.